# jQuery Media Plugin Full height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery Media Plugin to view PDF files in the browser. I have a popup that comes up which loads the PDF using jQuery Media Plugin. However, the media plugin seems to only allow defining a fixed width and height like this:

```
$('a.media').media({width:500, height:400});
```

I would like to set it so that its 100% wide and tall. I couldnt find any answers online. I have currently used `$(document).height()` and `$(document).width()` to get the values and set that like this:

```
    xheight = $(document).height();
    ywidth = $(document).width();
    $('a.media').media({width:ywidth, height:xheight});
```

This does seem to work but I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it and if it will work across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Document `height` and `width` get after document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    xheight = $(document).height();
    ywidth = $(document).width();
    $('a.media').media({width:ywidth, height:xheight});
});
```

I hope this will work for you